# Retrieve attribute value from parent and display it as an attribute in the child

Tags: xml, xslt

```
<Root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">    
<Package ID="b7137f22-31da-4d90-971c-b6baad654c96" BusinessID="P_000137" Path="/Package/Product/Launch_Entity" xsi:type="Package_Private_Line">
    <Category_ID Product_Line_ID="63">63</Category_ID>
    <Compatibility_Rules ID="32fd84b4-7b9b-40e2-8265-8e2e4f856a8d">
        <Rule_Event ID="992f04cb-6bd1-42bb-9578-87793dd38aca">
            <Name>Entity Selection</Name>
        </Rule_Event><Rule_Name>Private Line Exclusions</Rule_Name>
        <Rule_Statement ID="d0cc0700-2199-4a51-af68-72dfe27d878f">
            <Description>IF package is Private line THEN exclude Ethernet Switched Access (ESA)</Description>
            <Actions ID="d8165dda-7f8b-4c44-8400-eb081c0ec79c">
                <Then>THEN exclude Ethernet Switched Access (ESA</Then>
                <Entity>PSpec_000164</Entity><Operand ID="f74c6bf3-2718-4f8c-90e1-ead1257edc3a">
                    <Name>EXCLUDE</Name>
                </Operand></Actions>
            <Conditions ID="12dd11ea-bfe7-4ef3-b35c-f06cc90b1b6b">
                <If>IF package is Private Line</If>
                <Operand ID="8d041d93-77c7-46ac-938d-753596b8535c">
                    <Name>EXISTS</Name>
                </Operand>
                <Entity>P_000137</Entity>
            </Conditions></Rule_Statement>
    </Compatibility_Rules>
</Package>
</Root>
```

The above is the XML I am trying to transform. 
I need to display the Compatibility_Rules as:

```
<attribute><name>Compatibility Rules</name><value GUID="b7137f22-31da-4d90-971c-b6baad654c96"></value>
```

The GUID above is the ID attribute of Package. I have no clue how can this be achieved.

Comment: It's unclear what output structure you want. Also, show us what you've tried or at least give us an idea of what you've looked into. Then, people will likely help.

Answer (score 1):

To select the ID attribute of the parent element:

```
../*/@ID
```

Applied in XSLT in a template for `Compatability_Rules` using an [Attribute Value Template](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates):

```
<xsl:template match="Compatibility_Rules">
    <attribute>
            <name>
                <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
            </name>
            <value GUID="{../*/@ID}"></value>
    </attribute>
</xsl:template>
```